# Create two pages of Rave Report

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I'm new to Rave Report and need to do some changes on the existing report.
I need to create a report with additional page that have Terms & Conditions as Last Page for every report

Eg: the current report only have one page, now it will need have two pages. Page 1 is the data with template and Page 2 is blank page with text for T&C.

I've tried create Report1>Page1 for Date Template, and Report1>Page2 for T&C. It works fine if only one report printed at a time. But when i print multiple reports at a time, the sequence of the page printed is not correct. It will print all the Data Template page, then only the T&C page. So, the PageNo will be incorrect.

Can anyone advise me on how to do it?
Hope you can understand what I'm trying to say and ask. Thanks

I'm using Rave Report 7.0.3(Visual Designer).

Answer (score 0):

On the right side navigation, select your current Report (Report1), and on the left menu, you will see a "PageList" section, where you add your pages in the order you wish to print them.  Everything should work fine.  Good luck.

Comment: I've tried that. Everything works fine when I tick one, means print only one report at one time. But for my system, it allow user to tick many report and click print. That is when the report will jumble up. Have any idea how and why?

Comment: Did you try setting the band type as "detail"?